# Create and use Babel plugin without making it a npm module

Tags: node.js, babeljs

In my project, I'm using Babel 6 with the require hook. I need to load a custom babel plugin that I wrote. But do I really need to publish my plugin using npm first, and then include the plugin name in my main project's `.babelrc`?

Is there any way to just directly load the plugin code? In other words, can I just load the following directly?

```
export default function({types: t }) {
  return {
    visitor: {
      ...
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Where you list your plugins in your .babelrc, provide *the path to your plugin* instead of your standard published plugin name.

```
"plugins": ["transform-react-jsx", "./your/plugin/location"]
```

When exporting your plugin function, you'll probably need to use `module.exports =` instead of `export default`, since ES2015 modules haven't been fully implemented in Node yet.

Comment: Thank you! I wish this was more apparent on babel's website/documentation.

Comment: What exactly should the path be relative to?

Comment: It's relative to every file which babel runs on ... which means it's always changing. Best bet it so use `path.resolve` to get an absolute path to your plugin and use that

Answer (score 1):

This is my entire `babel.config.js` file.

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);

  const presets = ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"];
  const plugins = [ 
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator", { "proposal": "minimal" }],
    "c:\\projects\\my-babel-plugin"
  ];

  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
}
```

First item in the plugins array is a [plugin with options](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins#plugin-options) in form of an array. Second item is my own local plugin.

Inside of `my-babel-plugin` folder there needs to be a `package.json` with the "main" entry, usually `"main": "lib/index.js"` or `"main": "src/index.js"`.